# Typescript: How to add type guards for enums in union types?

Tags: types, enums, typescript

The following code gives errors:

1. The left-hand side of an 'instanceof' expression must be of type 'any', an object or a type parameter.
2. Type 'E | C'  is not assignable to type 'E'. Type 'C'  is not assignable to type 'E'.

```
    enum E { FIRST = 1, SECOND = 2 }; 

    class C {
        value: E;    

        constructor(arg: C | E) {
            if (arg instanceof C) { // 1.
                this.value = arg.value;
            } else {
               this.value = arg; // 2.
            }
        }
    }

    var a: C = new C(E.SECOND);
    console.log('a.value = ' + a.value);

    var b: C = new C(a);
    console.log('b.value = ' + b.value);
```

Despite the errors the code seems to compile fine on [TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=enum%20E%20%7B%20FIRST%20%3D%201%2C%20SECOND%20%3D%202%20%7D%3B%0A%0Aclass%20C%20%7B%0A%09value%3A%20E%3B%0A%09%0A%09constructor(arg%3A%20C%20%7C%20E)%20%7B%0A%09%09if%20(arg%20instanceof%20C)%20%7B%0A%09%09%09this.value%20%3D%20arg.value%3B%0A%09%09%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%09%09%09this.value%20%3D%20arg%3B%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Avar%20a%3A%20C%20%3D%20new%20C(E.SECOND)%3B%0Aconsole.log('a.value%20%3D%20'%20%2B%20a.value)%3B%0A%0Avar%20b%3A%20C%20%3D%20new%20C(a)%3B%0Aconsole.log('b.value%20%3D%20'%20%2B%20b.value)%3B) and does the expected.

Comment: PS: An easy work around would be to replace the union type with type 'any', though that would contradict the idea of TypeScript.

Answer (score 6):

Two issues.

There's a bug in the compiler that `instanceof` isn't allowed on union types when one of its constituents isn't an object type. This is being fixed (https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2775)

The other thing is that `instanceof` does not cause narrowing in the `else` block (https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1719) because failing an `instanceof` check doesn't *necessarily* mean the object doesn't match the specified interface. This is currently "by design" but I'd encourage you to leave a comment that you find this behavior surprising or undesirable (I certainly do).

Answer (score 3):

Ryan is, of course, both eloquent and accurate, but I can offer you a *temporary* workaround that you may find useful. Despite its possible use, please don't accept this as the answer as long-term the resolution of the issues related to type guards will be better.

```
class C {
    value: E;    

    constructor(arg: C | number) {
        if(typeof arg === 'number') {
            this.value = arg;
        } else {
            this.value = arg.value;
        }
    }
}
```

This rather unsavoury solution leans on the fact that enums and numbers happily play together. You also benefit from the side-effect of `typeof` checks narrowing the `else` statement.

Comment: I'll go with this fix, because enum/number args are far more frequent, so the test for it should come 1st anyway.